# Salvar um formulário jsp

Tags: java, spring

Quando salvo um formulário, isto é, vai para a classe controlle do Spring,
Preciso que o mesmo lance uma exceção, para avisar o usuário que algum campo é obrigatório.

No JSP está assim:

```
         <c:if test="${not empty param.e}">
         <div class="form-group has-error">
         <label for="inputError" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 control-label no-padding-right">
         <i class="ace-icon fa fa-times-circle"></i> Campos com * são obrigatórios !</label>
         </div>
         </c:if>
```

No controlle está assim:

```
     @RequestMapping("salvarPais")
     @Transactional
     public String cadastrar(PaisEntity pais, Model model) {
        if (pais.getDescricao() == null || pais.getDescricao().isEmpty()) {
            model.addAttribute("e", "e");
            return "redirect:novoPais";
        }
        String pagina = "";
        if (pais.getId() == null) {
            pagina = "redirect:novoPais/?i=ok";
        } else {
            pagina = "redirect:editarPais?id=" + pais.getId() + "&a=ok";
        }
        repository.salvar(pais);
        return pagina;
     }
```

O problema é que ao salvar e ao emitir a mensagem de erro corretamente, ele limpa os outros campos.

Qual seria a melhor forma ?

Comment: Sua única necessidade é tornar determinado campo do seu formulário obrigatório?

Comment: @R.Santos você está falando desta tag required="", dentro do imput  ?

Comment: Depende o que você precisa, se sua única necessidade era de tornar o campo obrigatório eu iria te sugerir isso

Comment: Não queria assim.

Mas de qualquer maneira, preciso de mudar o retorno do controller.

Por exemplo, Tenho que fazer uma consulta e validar se a informação já existe no banco de dados.